# Bootstrap Maxlength plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, maxlength

I'm using the bootstrap maxlength plugin source: 
http://mimo84.github.io/bootstrap-maxlength/

A very neat plugin for styling the maxlength attribute.
I now have a problem when I dynamically create a new text input and texture with a maxlength.

After the creation, I do a new call with:

```
     $('#newIdOfTextfield').maxlength();
```

But there is no activation of the plugin. Does anyone have a clue where to look, or have the answer to it?

I have a subscriber function of, When i put an alert within the function i get the alert in my screen, so after i add something to the variabel fields it calls the feature.

```
self.variableFields.subscribe(function(changes) {
    if (changes[0].status == 'added') {
        $('input[maxlength],textarea[maxlength]').maxlength({
            alwaysShow: true
        });
    }
}, null, 'arrayChange');
```

The output is this:

```
    <!-- ko foreach: variableFields -->

            <!-- ko if: fieldType == 'text' -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-lg-3 col-md-3" data-bind="text: fieldTitle"></label>
              <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7">
                <input type="text" maxlength="150" class="form-control" placeholder="" data-bind="value: fieldValue">
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- /ko -->
```

With static fields it is just fine, but with auto created fields it doenst work with the dynamic added field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the order of execution is not what you expect. I think this is happening:

1. You update variableFields
2. The subscriber is called & the DOM starts to be rendered
3. The subscriber will execute first. It tries to initiate the plugin, but nothing is there for it to work on.
4. The DOM is updated - after the subscriber!

You could try fixing it by using the afterRender event on your foreach. Set up your HTML like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: {data: variableFields, afterRender: doPlugin} -->
```

Then add a method to your view-model called doPlugin, which sets up all plugins needed in your new HTML:

```
self.doPlugin = function() {
    $('input[maxlength],textarea[maxlength]').maxlength({
        alwaysShow: true
    });
}
```

This will works as follows:

1. You update variableFields
2. The DOM starts to be rendered
3. The DOM is updated and afterRender fires
4. doPlugin is called
5. Your code now has some valid DOM elements to work against

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a million. afterRender was indeed the function I needed.
Great description and explanation very much thank you